Which USB to Ethernet adapter supports hardware timestamps for non PTP packets?
We are looking for a USB to Ethernet Adapter that supports PTP and also is able to h/w time stamp NON PTP Packets. We need this for capturing packets with high precision and also do synchronisation using PTP / IEEE 1588.
We did find such a hardware that supports PTP synchronization: https://www.asix.com.tw/en/product/USBEthernet/Super-Speed_USB_Ethernet/AX88279
but sadly, after a short discussion with their techincal support , they informed that AX88279 will only record timestamps when it detects PTP protocol packets. For normal packet formats, timestamps cannot be recorded.
Is anyone aware any such hardware that supports PTP  ,takes hardstamps for non-PTP packets? We are especially looking for an USB-Eth adapter.

What are you planning on using this ethernet adapter with? How many do you need? Does it absolutely have to be USB based? Besides Asix, Realtek is basically the only other notable manufacturer of USB NICs, and as far as I'm aware, they only offer limited PTP support (and even then, often only if you build the drivers from the source.) You'll probably have much better luck with another vendor (e.g. Intel) if it at all works with your hardware setup.

The ethernet adapter will be connected to other ECUs on ethernet side and PC on usb side, which will be sending sensor data which is time sensitive.  Therefore hardware time stamping is desired on receiver side to correlate them to best possible precision. I was just looking at convenient plug and play solutions, and USB is in every laptop so far. I was considering it to be USB based. You are right, Realtek seems to be unreliable.I might indeed consider Intel(i dint find any other vendor, may be Marvell?), though using it as a external device makes it cost inefficient. Thank you for the reply.

The question doesn't seem to mention which operating system is intended. Is there a preference for Windows or Linux, as that could impact possible solutions.


Intel Ethernet Controllers: (I210, I225, etc.) offer the most robust hardware timestamping support but generally come as PCIe cards.

Marvell Ethernet controllers: Marvell 88E1512, Marvell Alaska 88E1543, Marvell AQtion AQC107.

Realtek Ethernet Controllers: Realtek RTL8153, Realtek RTL8111.

FPGA-based solutions may be customized to meet your exact timestamping needs for all packet types.

Using an external PCIe enclosure with a Thunderbolt interface could allow you to use a PCIe Ethernet card with USB-like connectivity.


Unfortunately, as of now, there are no widely available USB-to-Ethernet adapters that fully meet the requirement of hardware timestamping for non-PTP packets along with PTP support. You may need to explore a custom hardware solution or a more advanced network interface card in an external enclosure.
Recommendations:
For high-precision timing, Marvell controllers like the 88E1543 or 88E1512 might be better suited for PTP synchronization and hardware timestamping, but these would require more specific setups such as embedded systems or PCIe-based solutions.
Realtek RTL8153 can work for basic USB-to-Ethernet connectivity but might fall short on the precision required for non-PTP packet timestamping.
If USB is essential, combining a Thunderbolt-to-PCIe enclosure with a Marvell or Intel NIC may offer the best solution for your needs.

Great help! Thanks a lot.
